# How to delete everything inside a directory, without an specific folder and it's content

Tags: shell, find

My folder structure looks like that:

```
./build
./module/build
./source
```

All I want to keep is ./build and it's content.

The command `find . \! -path ./build -delete` does not delete `./build`, but all of it's content.

How to avoid that?

Comment: Fixed the build/built typo in my question. Sorry for that.

Comment: How to use -prune in that example?

Comment: @Anthon, `Because  -delete  implies  -depth,  you  cannot  usefully  use -prune and -delete
              together.
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
find . \! \( -wholename "./build/*" -o -wholename ./build \) -delete
```

If you run:

```
rm -rf /tmp/tmp2
mkdir /tmp/tmp2
cd /tmp/tmp2

mkdir -p build module/build source
touch .hidden build/abc build/abc2 source/def module/build/ghi

find . \! \( -wholename "./build/*" -o -wholename ./build \) -delete

find .
```

your output will be:

```
./build
./build/abc
```

This is much safer than trying to parse the output of `ls`, where you have to take care of file or directory names with spaces or even worse with newlines embedded, `find` handles those correctly.

Comment: i get this error when trying this command: `find: paths must precede expression: ./build/cshark-bg-login-box@2x.758e95a1aa9bb6ed87f4.png
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]`

Comment: @MarioHofer That error is caused by your `build` directory having multiple files and my `find` command not quoting the `*` (which my test program missed because I created only one file under `build`), fixed that.

Comment: Works! This looks like the cleanest version for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take advantage of the shell (bash) you are using:

```
shopt -s extglob
rm -rfvi ./!(build)
```

Comment: are you sure that `f` and `i` options of `rm` work well together? They are kind of opposite.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou I've added `-vi` just in case someone blindly copy&paste this command, in real these options these options should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Jimmij's perfect answer:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Is loading extended pattern matching into bash. From `man bash`:

```
If the extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin, several
extended pattern matching operators are recognized.  In  the  following
description, a pattern-list is a list of one or more patterns separated
by a |.  Composite patterns may be formed using  one  or  more  of  the
following sub-patterns:

      ?(pattern-list)
             Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
      *(pattern-list)
             Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
      +(pattern-list)
             Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
      @(pattern-list)
             Matches one of the given patterns
      !(pattern-list)
             Matches anything except one of the given patterns
```

Therefore:

```
rm -rfvi ./!(build)
```

Gets evaluated as delete everything except this given pattern.

Comment: How to include dot leading file names into this pattern?

Comment: `rm -vf ./!(something.keepme) && rm -vf ./.*` is the lazy way. There are more elegant solutions than this, for sure. Be careful.

Comment: Yepp, that works! So I use `rm -rf ./!(build) && rm -rf .*` now

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 ! -name build -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

`-maxdepth 1`   will only will only find things in the current folder, not any levels deeper.

`-mindepth 1`   will make sure to exclude `.` from the file listing (which denotes the current directory).

`! -name build`   will make sure no matches return that have a name *exactly* matchisg 'build'. So if you had a folder called 'build1' it would also be  removed if you ran this command.

`-exec command {} \;` will execute the command and directly pass the argument to it. This allows names with spaces and odd characters to work as well. The `\;` is needed at the end to let find know that it has reached the end of the command you have passed it.

Before running the command that will actually perform the deletion you should run this just to be sure:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 ! -name build -exec echo {} \;
```

This will just echo all the filenames and make sure you have the syntax correct before you substitute in the command you want to perform to each item.

Answer (score 0):

`find . \! -path ./build -do_something` does not act on `./build`, but it traverses it, to match the files under it. To tell find not to traverse a directory, pass the action `-prune`.

```
find . -path ./build -prune -o . -o -delete
```

“If the full path is `./build` then don't traverse it, else if it's the current directory then do nothing, else delete the file.”